# CLion Web API functions "Unresolved function or method"

Tags: javascript, clion, webapi

Can someone please help me to configure CLion to be able to resolve Web API functions in JavaScript files?  This is a made-up example of what I see:

[image: CLion IDE view]

The `URL`, `fetch()` and the `DOMParser()` web API calls all don't resolve in the editor.  When I mouse over these the pop-up shows "Unresolved function or method".  I've tried Googling for a few hours now and just cannot figure out what I'm meant to do to get these to be resolved.  I'm not dealing with a Node.js project or anything, just HTML and JavaScript (but I'm open to whatever configuration I might need to apply).  Objects and their properties defined in the file do resolve correctly.

I'm using "CLion 2023.1"

TIA